# cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}

Tags: wchar-t, lpcstr, dn

Please help me with this code, I don't know how to change it so I can fix it and run it

std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(filename.begin(), filename.end());

```
hBitmapG = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), stemp.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP,
                  0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

if (!hBitmapG) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::wstring errorMsg = L"Failed to LoadImage - '" + stemp + L"', error code (" + std::to_wstring((long long)err) + L")";
    MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg.c_str(), L"WinCanvas::DrawBitmap()", MB_OK);

    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);    // Post a message to destroy (shutdown) the program
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: A question that gets asked literally every single day. May want to do some research up front. And since you are clearly *completely* unfamiliar with the Windows API, consider using standard tooling (Visual Studio). It'll make discovering solutions so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MessageBoxW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) function to use wide characters in MessageBox.